# "Invalid or unitialized Zip object" Error when closing DOCX file

Tags: php, docx

When I try to use this code to count pages in a .docx file I always receive the error:

> "Warning: ZipArchive::close(): Invalid or unitialized Zip object in"

```
function PageCount_DOCX($file) {
    $pageCount = 0;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if($zip->open($file) === true) {
        if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)  {
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            $zip->close();
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            $pageCount = $xml->Pages;
        }
        $zip->close();
    }

    return $pageCount;
}
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have 2 zip closes in the code, the second one will generate the error as you already closed the zip.

```
function PageCount_DOCX($file) {
    $pageCount = 0;

    $zip = new ZipArchive();

    if($zip->open($file) === true) {
        if(($index = $zip->locateName('docProps/app.xml')) !== false)  {
            $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
            // remove this one
            //$zip->close();
            $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            $pageCount = $xml->Pages;
        }
        // or remove this one
        $zip->close();
    }

    return $pageCount;
}
```